# Fluentd installation - Centos

Tags: linux, centos, fluentd, syslog

I am trying to install Fluentd software on Centos servers and I get the error below:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fluentd:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /opt/rh/rh-ruby26/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/msgpack-1.6.0/ext/msgpack
/opt/rh/rh-ruby26/root/usr/bin/ruby -I /opt/rh/rh-ruby26/root/usr/share/rubygems -r ./siteconf20221204-2069-z0rswh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /opt/rh/rh-ruby26/root/usr/share/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I saw in previous guides that I need to complete these commands:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

However, when I tried to run the command I get this error:\

bash: xcode-select: command not found

Someone can assist please?
Thanks!!!

Install Fluentd on centos server

[I get this error when I've run "sudo yum install ruby-devel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVA5b.png)

Comment: Run `sudo yum install ruby-devel` and then reinstall. `xcode` commands are for macOS, not CentOS.

Comment: @Azeem, Thanks - I've run 'sudo yum install ruby-devel'. What next? Please send the full commands that I need to run.

Comment: @Azeem see the screenshot when I run again the "gem install fluentd".

Comment: Your ruby version is lower than what is required. See that error message. There's a version difference.

Comment: Regarding errors and logs, always post copy and paste text instead of images.